# How to type any given string, which contains special characters, using python's keyboard module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

I wanted to type a very simple "(hello)", throught the key board module

```
import keyboard
s="(hello)"
keyboard.write(s)
```

this gives me a variety of errors, which i believe stems from the fact that '(' and ')' are un-mapped special characters, that require some user-defined mapping?

**Note:**
the following commands works without any error:

```
import keyboard
s="hello"
keyboard.write(s)
```

Comment: Can you type "(" by using this `keyboard.write('shift+8')` ?

Comment: typing shift+8 works, but what if '(' or any other special character is a part of a string that i want to write? then it doesn't work. I don't what to do about that

Comment: @TheOneMusic Nope :(

Comment: @TheOneMusic Unfortunately, that doesnt work either

Comment: What is the error raised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the keyboard package source. The keyboard.write() as of (28 May 2020) cannot do this. It can only simulate the non modified versions of the keys. You need to use other functions in the keyboard package to achieve combination key presses.

Workaround / Solution, (Manually simulate the key press by using other functions in the keyboard package):

```
import keyboard

# This line will simulate the "shift+9" combination which is "(" character.
keyboard.press("shift"); keyboard.press("9"); keyboard.release("9"); keyboard.release("shift")
```

Keyboard.write() processes the input string character by character as key press followed by key release before moving to next character. So you can only get the base versions of the keys. The lookup used by keyboard.write() for the combination characters is either not implemented correctly or not intended to work for combination characters. In your case for "(" or ")" it will throw StopIteration exception.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had ended up with almost the same conclusion, but is more reassuring coming form a professional!